# When using dual monitors, some software maximize only into the primary display?

Tags: multiple-monitors

When using multiple displays in Ubuntu, If I try to maximize some applications while in the secondary display, the application will move to the primary display and then maximize. I just checked whether only the apps executed in the secondary display can be maximized in it. But its not true.

First when I opened Gedit in the primary display, I took it to the other display and maximized. It went back to the primary display. Then I again opened a new Gedit and tried to do the same thing. Now it maximized in the secondary display. Why is this happening? How to fix it?

PS : Apps like Chrome are also effected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [well-known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/751605). A [fix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/751605/comments/35) is on its way.